# Where can I find the 'About' sections for runnable java jars?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I've developed a small app for someone.
I'm on windows, he's on a Mac.

He now tells me that in the "about" section he can see the package name I used.
I do not know how to access this menu on windows, he tells me it's right next to the apple button.

I used a nondescript name for the package, and he thinks it's ugly.
So...where would I find the settings for that in Eclipse?

I'll edit the question if it's too unclear...
But right now it shows something like com.foo.bar.etc

Stuff like that.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behaviour when you create a Java application and run it on MacOS. Give [Macify](http://simplericity.com/2007/10/02/1191336060000.html) a look - it allows you to integrate your Java app nicely with macos without breaking platform compatibility.